# Combining multiple associative arrays efficiently on an ID key

Tags: php, entity-attribute-value

I have a bunch of php arrays that look like this (please don't ask why, I'm just doing my job...All I will say is EAV...):

```
$firstNames = ([accountId] => 100, [firstName] => 'John'
               [accountId] => 101, [firstName] => 'Fred');


$lastNames =  ([accountId] => 100, [lastName] => 'Doe'
               [accountId] => 101, [lastName] => 'Bloggs');


$city      =  ([accountId] => 100, [city] => 'New York'
               [accountId] => 101, [city] => 'Cambridge');


$country   =  ([accountId] => 100, [country] => 'USA'
               [accountId] => 101, [country] => 'UK');
```

etc etc.

I have to combine them into one array:

```
$userDetails =  ([accountId] => 100, [firstName] => "John", [lastName] => "Doe", 
                 [city] => "New York", [country] => "USA");
```

My feeling is the correct answer would be to break these attributes out of EAV and model them correctly.  But I can't.  It would also be possible to do self-join upon self-join in the db, but I have simplified the example and this is not really possible - and I've been told to do it this way...There could be a bunch of additional fields tacked on as well, later.

So what is the best way to produce one associative array, merging on accountId in PHP?  Is there a function, or do I need to loop round and round etc.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to use 5 `foreach` loops, are you able to do that or do you need code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This nested `foreach` should do it:

```
$result = array();

foreach (array('firstNames' => 'firstName', 'lastNames' => 'lastName', 'city' => 'city', 'country' => 'country') as $srcArr => $arrKey) {
  foreach ($$srcArr as $item) {
    if (!isset($result[$item['accountId']])) {
      $result[$item['accountId']] = $item;
    } else {
      $result[$item['accountId']][$arrKey] = $item[$arrKey];
    }
  }
}

var_dump($result);
```

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/iaXYyM)

Comment: You're missing `$result[$item['accountId']]` initialization, and you take a look at `$userDetails`, this shouldn't work :) Would you mind if I take your answer and fix your bugs? :)

Comment: Awesome - thanks very much to both of you for the quick answer

Comment: @DaveRandom ah, my bad :) I didn't realize that `$userDetail` is output, not just another input array. But I still don't like `isset($result[$item['accountId']]['accountId'])`, I'd go for:

    `if (!isset($result[$item['accountId']])){
    $result[$item['accountId']] = $item;
} else {
    $result[$item['accountId']][$arrKey] = $item[$arrKey];
}`

Comment: @Vyktor That would work, it makes more sense it terms of var initialisation I suppose. I get lazy with PHP arrays, because as long as the main variable is initialised as an array it doesn't complain about recursive level creation - you can do `$myVar = array(); $myVar['level1']['level2']['level3'] = 'value';` and it won't complain about it, but really one should initialise the inner levels first. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @DaveRandom now it's worth +1 :) I think it's worth to put perfect codes here, may google queries end up just on stackowerflow .)